# video_player - Half of the video is green

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the **video_player** plugin and I'm trying to run this video on it but in my app half is on **green screen**.

What can that be?

How it looks on my device: (Android 6.0)

Information:

**Code:**

```
Container(
                height: widget.size.height,
                width: widget.size.width,
                color: primary,
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipRect(
                        child: OverflowBox(
                            maxWidth: double.infinity,
                            maxHeight: double.infinity,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: FittedBox(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Container(
                                    width: widget.size.width,
                                    height: widget.size.height,
                                    child: AspectRatio(
                                        aspectRatio: 16.0 / 9.0,
                                        child: VideoPlayer(
                                            _videoPlayerController))))))
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

**Image Screen:**
[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml:**
`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

**Size video:**
`1024x576`

**Flutter doctor -v:**

```
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.26.0-12.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.18363.1139], locale
    pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-12.0.pre at G:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision a706cd2112 (7 weeks ago), 2021-01-14 18:20:26 -0500
    • Engine revision effb529ece
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-224.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Matheus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Matheus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\Matheus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: G:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at G:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Matheus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.19.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Lenovo K10a40 (mobile) • 0026760053 • android-arm • Android 6.0 (API 23)

• No issues found!
```